# How can I plot points (plot a ggplot for example) onto a Tanakaplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to create a map for my PhD of some sampling locations in the rainforest, and I thought it would be cool to represent their elevation on the map as well, since it can be significant.

After much experimentation with plotting my points on DEM rasters I decided it is not the most visually clear way of doing it so I thought to turn the raster into a contour and represent it that way. So I found this wonderful **tanaka package** to create an astonishing contoured elevation map, and it looks great.

However now I run into the problem that I cannot seem to find the way how to **plot my sampling points onto the tanaka plot.**

I made a nice ggplot to represent the shape and color of the points with their longitude and latitude which would be great if I could integrate it. Is there a way?

Here are my lines for the tanakaplot and the ggplot.

```
tanaka(park, breaks = seq(25,250,25), legend.pos = "topright", 
       legend.title = "Elevation\n(meters)", 
       col = brewer.pal(n = 8, name = "Blues"))

ggplot(data = worldmap) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_point(data = necropsies, 
             aes(x = lng, y = lat, color = anthrax, shape = anthrax), size = 2) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("green", "red")) +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-7.37, -7.255), ylim = c(5.775, 5.89))
```

Comment: The `metR` package provides "Tanaka plots" based on ggplot2, so it might be easier to add a layer with your points (it seems the `tanaka` package you used is not based on ggplot2)

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!

 Yes, Tanakaplots does not seem to be compatible with ggplot. I tried using metR package geom_contour_tanaka but I am really having trouble with the data. In all the guides the first thing they seem to do with the data is create a gh.z column, which will later be used as "z" value. Could someone please help me what this exactly means and if it is necessary for elevation tanaka plot?

Thank you very much again! (:

Kamilla